# How to Handle JWTs in FastAPI

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

```py
import jwt


payload_data = {
    'sub': '1010',
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'nickname': 'john'
}

secret = 'my_super_secret'
token = jwt.encode(payload=payload_data, key=secret)
print(token)
```

### Scripts Description

| Script | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `examples/create_jwt_hs256.py` | Creates and prints out a JWT using the **HS256** algorithm |

- I use this part of Code to Generate also a Token :

```py
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: Optional[timedelta] = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)

    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)

    return encoded_jwt
```

Here I try to find a better way of using a JWT to handle it in FastAPI.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: My Question is what is the Safe way and a good way to handle a JWT in FastAPI ?

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/ ?